# How to find out all the dependency class names of one class?

Tags: java, classloader

I have a big list of classes, a lot of them are not used any more.

I know the entries class, I'd like to know all its child classes. I know read class binary would help, wondering whether there is any better way.

We are not using class.forName.

thanks.

Comment: Similar topics: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/162551/how-to-find-unused-dead-code-in-java-projects and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786708/how-to-check-dependencies-between-jar-files

Answer (score 1):

I'd rather use a static code analysis tool like:

- [UCDetector](http://www.ucdetector.org/)
- [FindBugs](http://findbugs.sourceforge.net/)

These do not find dependencies, but find "dead code". And that's what you are trying to achieve as far as I understand.

Comment: I tried UCDetector, it only show unused pieces of code within file, but not tell which class file is useless. Those class files are suppose to be referenced in various configuration files. 
For findbugs, I am not seeing any errors in my existing project. 

I guess I need to try the reflection. 

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Check out [Class Dependency Analyzer](http://www.dependency-analyzer.org/)