# How to get all dependency jars from build.xml

Tags: ant, jar, build.xml

I have several very big ant build.xml files.
Someone know tool or program for get all dependency jar files from build.xml ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check [How To Check Dependencies Between Jar Files?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786708/how-to-check-dependencies-between-jar-files).

http://www.jboss.org/tattletale or jdepend could help in getting dependencies between jars.

If you want to extract dependencies from a given build.xml , one option is to write XML parser and process ant file. Not an easy task.  Another option will be write a listener for each build task. If the task is javac then query its classpath.