# java.lang.ClassCastException: antlr.CommonToken cannot be cast to antlr.Token in Jenkins Checkstyle report

Tags: java, jenkins, antlr, checkstyle

I am using checkstyle 5.5 for my project and building using Jenkins 1.462.

My project builds successfully, but every java class in my project causes Checkstyle to create a high priority, `TreeWalker` error like below:

> ProductComparisonService.java:0, TreeWalker, Priority: High Got an
>   exception - java.lang.ClassCastException: antlr.CommonToken cannot be
>   cast to antlr.Token
>
> No description available. Please upgrade to latest checkstyle version.

I tried upgrading to checkstyle 5.6 but that did not solve the problem.  I'd appreciate any ideas.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a conflicting version of antlr(works) in some other plugin that you're using, and that is interfering in the classloader. You need to unload that other plugin.

I haven't myself tested, but here are some recommended tools that might be able to find the offending jar for you:

- [JarAnalyzer](http://www.kirkk.com/main/Main/JarAnalyzer), as recommended in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4417820/how-to-list-dependencies-of-a-jar)
- [JBoss TattleTale](http://www.jboss.org/tattletale), as recommended [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/786708/how-to-check-dependencies-between-jar-files)
- [Dependency Finder](http://depfind.sourceforge.net/)

Comment: I've got about 90 other jars in the project. Is there an easy way that you know of to determine what is the offending jar?

Comment: @KamikazeMercenary added some tools for you. Haven't tried myself though, so don't know if it is easy or not.