# Make sure that all Java classes referenced inside JAR/classpath are present in the JAR/classpath

Tags: java, jar, code-analysis

I want to make sure that a JAR won't throw NoClassDefinitionFound exception before it is deployed to a server. More advanced requirement is to be able to specify additional class paths.

How this can be done?

Comment: It cannot. I can always add another Jar later that will cause the error.

Comment: Check this might be helpful http://stackoverflow.com/questions/250166/noclassdeffounderror-while-trying-to-run-my-jar-with-java-exe-jar-whats-wron

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/786708/how-to-check-dependencies-between-jar-files

Answer (score 0):

In general it is not possible since your JAR file can load classes dynamically using `Class.forName()` or `ClassLoader.loadClass()` methods

I would say that the proper approach is to use some dependency management tool during your build process which will assemble all the dependencies for you.

Maven war plugin will do it for you automatically

Comment: JVM must be able to extract Class.forName() and ClassLoader.loadClass() calls and FQNs passed to them from bytecode, right? In that case why other tool can't?

Comment: Cause in general the actual values are known only in runtime - the web application itself is a good example: application server doesn't know what classes to load until it parses web.xml or scans the jars for annotations